# Approximating functions by Taylor.

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation-theory

I want to apply the Taylor for approximating function
$$\begin{align}f(t,x,v)=f(t,x_{k},v_{k})+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,x_{k},v_{k}) (x-x_{k})+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial v }(t,x_{k},v_{k})(v-v_{k})\end{align}+O(h^{2})$$
where  $t$ independent variable and two dependent variables $x$ and $v$.

Is that correct?

Comment: If $x-x_k=\mathcal{O}(h)$ and $v-v_k=\mathcal{O}(h)$, yes.

Comment: It is not correct because we don't know what $h$ is. Also it will not necessarily lead to a useful approximation because we know very little, if not nothing, about the $O(h^2)$.

Comment: $$h=t_{k+1}-t_{k}$$ and $x,\ y$ dependent on $t$.

Answer (score 1):

What you are really doing is this: $$ f(t,x,v) = f(t_k,x_k,v_k) + \frac{df}{dt}(t_k,x_k,v_k)(t-t_k) + \mathcal{O}(h^2) $$ i.e $$ f(t,x,v) =  f(t_k,x_k,v_k) +\left [\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} \right ](t_k,x_k,v_k) (t-t_k) + \mathcal{O}(h^2) $$

Comment: You shouldn't use $\approx$ with $\mathcal{O}$-notation, since the $\mathcal{O}$-notation is not an approximation.

Comment: @ P. Siehr: updated thanks

Comment: I upvoted this because this is formally correct for *smooth* functions. The missing parts are 1) The hypothesis on $f,$, for example $\cal{C}^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$, same question for $x, v$. 2) Some information about the size of $O(h^2)$ if the OP wants to turn this into a useful approximation formula. 3) Some information about how the OP wants to use this.

Comment: many thanks, but why $C^{2}\left(\mathbb{R^{3}}\right)$, $f\in C^{2}\left(\left[a,b\right]\right) \ \mbox{when} \ t\in\left[a,b\right]$. Is that correct?

Comment: @work $f$ is a function of 3 variables, so it must be defined on some subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. This is necessary to speak about partial derivatives.

Comment: right 3 variable, but $x,v$ depend on $t$  i.e $x(t)$ and $v(t)$. !